# How to stop scripts that are constantly running, when 'terminate' option in executions does not work?

Tags: google-apps-script

We have recently noticed that some scripts have had running for 'days', and we cannot terminate them using the 'terminate' option on the executions page. Does anyone know another way to force a script to terminate?

Image of execution page;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YU1RBeTr25oi0ia9pUpAHEfa1Ti1C5D/view?usp=sharing

I have tried using the Terminate feature in executions, which has always worked in the past, but won't work for these 'constantly running scripts'. A message "Failed to Terminate Execution" displays at the bottom of the page after about 15 seconds (the message "Loading Data, this may take a few moments" is displayed prior to the error message).

Have reached out to Google Support, but they direct me back to stackoverflow.

- considering the scripts have apparently been running for days, I would except to be exceeding the 90min running time for scripts per day, and get the error "Service using too much computer time for one day" on any script running on this account, but that is not the case and other scripts are running fine.

Answer (score 1):

found below Issue Tracker page where Google employee states;

"It is a display bug, the script is not really running."

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129362501